# Process sequence of Observable<T>

Tags: rx-java

I am looking for a way to process a sequence of `Observables<T>`.

```
List.of(observable1, observable2, ..., observableN);
```

In a way, that if one of them fails all subsequent observables should be skipped and `error` reported. Or `success` if all observables complete without errors.

Comment: Put them into an `Observable<Observable<T>>` and then have a look at `flatMap` and/or `concatMap`.

Comment: How are observable1..N created? Is T the same for all Observables?

Comment: There is no specific way how observables are created. T is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If T is the same for all observables then just use `Observable.from()` to turn the list of observables into an Observable of Observables. Then use `Observable.concat()` to process each observable in sequence. Any errors will halt processing and call your subscribers onError().

The following assumes you have a variable declared as `List<Observable<Object>> observablesList`. Just substitute your item class in place of the `Object` class.

```java
Observable
    .concat(Observable.from(observablesList))    // The magic happens here.
    .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            // Called when all items from all observables have
            // been emitted.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // All errors end up here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object item) {
            // Do what you want with "item"
        }
    });
```